# Truncating numbers but they are not showing up the right number of characters

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to extract the first 6 numbers for the `hs10` variable, but I've been getting only 5 characters for some - is there a reason for this?

[image]

I have used this function

```
us_chn_tariffs_18$HS6 <- as.numeric(substr(format(us_chn_tariffs_18$hs10, scientific = F), 1, 6))
```

The `dput` is:

```
structure(list(hs10 = structure(c(208100000, 208902500, 301110010, 
301110020, 301110090, 301990390, 302230000, 302290110, 302290190, 
302420000, 302455000, 302595010, 302595090, 302740000, 302845000, 
302895077, 302912000, 303120022, 303120032, 303230000), label = "HS10 Product Code", format.stata = "%10.0f"), 
    tariff_max = structure(c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
    0.1), label = "US Import Tariff Increase (max)", format.stata = "%9.3f"), 
    tariff_scaled = structure(c(0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 
    0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 
    0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 
    0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 
    0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 
    0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 
    0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021, 0.0333333350718021
    ), label = "US Import Tariff Increase (scaled)", format.stata = "%9.3f"), 
    effective_mdate = structure(c(704, 704, 704, 704, 704, 704, 
    704, 704, 704, 704, 704, 704, 704, 704, 704, 704, 704, 704, 
    704, 704), label = "Month Variety First Targeted", format.stata = "%tm"), 
    month = c("9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", 
    "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9", "9"), treated = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    HS6 = structure(c(20810, 20890, 30111, 30111, 30111, 30199, 
    30223, 30229, 30229, 30242, 30245, 30259, 30259, 30274, 30284, 
    30289, 30291, 30312, 30312, 30323), label = "HS10 Product Code", format.stata = "%10.0f")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Thank you

Comment: Can I ask how I can use dput for an example please

Comment: You can just do `dput(head(us_chn_tariffs_18, 20))` from the original data before the transformation.  I would assume this anomaly is in the first 20 rows or else subset from a sample that shows the issue.  The dput gives the structure output, copy/paste that in your post by editing

Comment: Also, there was a comment by @onyambu about the 0 prefix removal while converting to numeric (`as.numeric`).  If that it the case, it is just a column type issue

Comment: That dput shows all of them with 5 characters `nchar(us_chn_tariffs_18$HS6)
 [1] 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5`

Comment: whereas if I use your code, it is all 6 characters `nchar(as.numeric(substr(format(us_chn_tariffs_18$hs10, scientific = F), 1, 6)))
 [1] 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6`

Comment: It's quite likely that some numbers start with zero perhaps? Can you post a sample which includes the rows which produce only five characters?

Comment: The generic code works, `as.numeric(substr(format("1234567890", scientific = F), 1, 6))`

Comment: I would suggest to try on a fresh R session as the output in HS6 is not matching with the code output

Comment: Hi all, as you can see from the dput example, the first row for `us_chn_tariffs_18$hs10` is 208100000 but `us_chn_tariffs_18$HS6` is 20810

Comment: When I run your code, I get 208100 for the first element of `us_chn_tariffs_18$HS6`. It sounds like there might be a package conflict somewhere. Try starting a fresh R session, and running only the code you have above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can see where the problem comes in, but cannot reproduce it quite exactly (as I've not imported from Stata). The Stata print format is `%10.0f`, which prints 10 characters, padding your digits with leading spaces. But your IDs are all 9 digits long, so the first character pulled from `substr` is a space, which `as.numeric` trims. Try reformating `hs10`:

```r
hs10 <-  c(
  208100000,
  208902500,
  301110010,
  301110020,
  301110090,
  301990390,
  302230000,
  302290110,
  302290190,
  302420000,
  302455000,
  302595010,
  302595090,
  302740000,
  302845000,
  302895077,
  302912000,
  303120022,
  303120032,
  303230000
)

# Reproducing the values you're getting

hs10_not_working <- sprintf(fmt = "%10.0f", hs10)

as.numeric(substr(format(hs10_not_working, scientific = F), 1, 6))
#>  [1] 20810 20890 30111 30111 30111 30199 30223 30229 30229 30242 30245 30259
#> [13] 30259 30274 30284 30289 30291 30312 30312 30323

# Corrected values

hs10_edited <- sprintf(fmt = "%-10.0f", hs10)

as.numeric(substr(format(hs10_edited, scientific = F), 1, 6))
#>  [1] 208100 208902 301110 301110 301110 301990 302230 302290 302290 302420
#> [11] 302455 302595 302595 302740 302845 302895 302912 303120 303120 303230
```

The new `sprintf(fmt = "%-10.0f", hs10)` part will left-align the numbers (`-` character) which will then mean the first 6 digits are extracted even if the value is only 9 digits.

Another simple solution would be to `trimws` before `substr`ing your variable:

```r
us_chn_tariffs_18$HS6 <- as.numeric(substr(trimws(format(us_chn_tariffs_18$hs10, scientific = F)), 1, 6))
```